# Custom dialog linear layout weight issue

Tags: android, xml, dialog, android-dialogfragment, android-layout-weight

I am using a `LinearLayout` view with a custom dialog ,when I run the code below, **weight** is not working correctly as the red view takes the green view's weight and verse vise as image below:

[image]

**but** when I use the same layout in another activity , *weight goes correctly* as the image below :

[image]

**ConfirmDialog.java**

```
  public class ConfirmDialog extends DialogFragment {

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            }

            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                return dialog;
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_confirm, null);

                return view;
            }

        }
```

---

**dialog_confirm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="7" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="#00ff00" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Make it easier for yourself. Set android:weightSum="1" and View's layout weights to the fractions of the width say 0.7 and 0.3. I find it easier to work with it that way. Apart from that you layout file seems to be fine.

Comment: One of the weirdest things I ever seen ...

Comment: may be this is the problem View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_confirm, null);

Comment: @DynamicMind I checked it before , not solved

Comment: Lets replace this line 'View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_confirm, null);' with View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_confirm, container, false);

Comment: Have been hit by this right now. It seems to be related to the absence of the title bar. If I avoid calling "dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)" things get fine.